# Add dynamic Numbers to the strings in sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

My plsql procedure has a variable that holds a concatenated string of values.

```
var_string1 :='ABC'
var_string2 :='APPLE'
var_string3 :='BIKE'
var_string4 :='DESK'

var_reas :=var_string1||','||var_string2||','||var_string3||','||var_string4);
```

I need to print these to a file as 4 different columns as below along with numbering

```
utl_file.put_line(filename,var_id,var_name,'1)'||var_string1 ,'2)'||var_string2 ,'3)'||var_string3 ,'1)'||var_string4);
```

The string var_string1 if blank then that should not be printed but the numbering has to be maintained.

```
utl_file.put_line(Filename,var_id,var_name,'1)'||var_string2 ,'2)'||var_string3 ,'3)'||var_string4);
```

I am thinking a counter on var_reas and then a loop to add the numbers, but i am unsure how to accomplish that .

Comment: I think I can help you, but it is unclear what data you are working with in your procedure. Do you have all 4 variables separated or do you only have the concatenated results of the 4 strings to work with? Are you able to share the full definition of your procedure?

Comment: @bunchesNbunches: I wrote a small for loop within the procedure to achieve